# Jmeter CSV DATA set config when stop thread on EOF is true. The tearDown group is not executed

Tags: csv, jmeter, teardown

Jmeter CSV DATA set config  when stop thread on EOF is true. The tearDown group is not executed.

[image]

Log error:

Stop Thread seen for thread tearDown Thread Group 1-1, reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file:C:/Users/673311/git/refund-batch-poc/BatchAutomation/batch_prod/11-02_Batch1_PP-Only.csv detected for **CSV DataSet**:CSV Data Set Config configured with stopThread:true, recycle:false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), when you put the CSV Data Set Config to the same level as [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - it will be applied to **all thread groups** therefore tearDown Thread Group will detect the file end and won't start any threads

If thread group doesn't start any threads no [samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) are executed.

Just move your CSV Data Set Config inside the "normal" Thread Group and you test should start working as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your quick response.